# Return struct of multi-array from user-defined function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct, allocation

I wrote a function as below, declared a struct of 2D array. size of this struct is initialized in function read_landmask.

```
struct landmask {
    double value;
};
landmask read_landmask(NcFile &dataFile,grid grid, parameters params) {
NcVar lm;
...
  size_t m=grid.lat.size();
  size_t n=grid.lon.size();

  landmask lmdomain[m][n];

  for (int i=0;i<m;++i){
    for (int j=0;j<n;++j){
      neighborpoints nbpoints=closest_distance(lmbnds.sizelat,lmbnds.sizelon,*lmdata, lmbnds.lat,lmbnds.lon, grid.lat[i], grid.lon[j]);
      lmdomain[i][j].value=interp2D_Cressman(nbpoints.lon, nbpoints.lat,nbpoints.val, grid.lat[i], grid.lon[j]);
    }
  };

  return lmdomain[m][n];
};
```

and in the main function, it is called like:

```
int main(){
landmask landmask_array=read_landmask(lmfile,grid,params);
cout<< landmask_array[3][2].value<< endl;
};
```

but the cout is error. Seems like the array is not return the whole 2D array, so I cannot put the indices of rows and columns.
Does anyone have ideas or experiences with this before?
Thanks

Comment: Provide a [mre], this is missing too many details to be compilable. Also include the actual error message in your question

Comment: Though at a glance you are returning a single `landmask` object, not an array, so `landmask_array[3][2]` cannot work

Comment: You cannot return an array from a function. Besides, VLAs are not a parr of C++ so `landmask lmdomain[m][n];` is not legal code. (Your compiler probably provides an extension that allows such code, but using it is *highly* not recommended). Use `std::vector`.

Comment: thanks for the comments. But is there anyway  (beside std::vector) to deal with multidimensional array in function? Well, my intention is to work with meteo data, which have usually high dimension (4D). I want to store them in struct so that I can manage them better in groups of different array/vector sizes (like windspeed.u windspeed.v...) or (current with lon, lat, value, time,....)

Comment: @HuyềnPizgy Any particular reason why you don't want to use `std::vector`? (Such as a vector of vectors of vectors of... in your case.) Of course, you can always wrap them with custom classes to give them some application semantics.

Comment: Yeah.  I tried with the vector<vector...>> and it worked well. thanks. Now it solved my problem. At first I didnt want to use std::vector because I dont want to use some thing like vector[i+j*n] because it looks confusing. But now I know how to do it in a better way. Thanks for the suggestion.